# Service not restarting after BOOT COMPLETED under Android Oreo

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, reboot

I am having a problem with my service not starting under android Oreo.
I have an Alarm manager who schedules a service at a specific time of the day. I have a BootCompleted Broadcast receiver who resets the alarm if the user rebooted their phone.

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            new AlarmHelper(context).setAlarm(timeInMillis); // i get timeInMilis from SharedPref

        }
    }
```

I have an AlarmReceiver which starts the service when the alarm manager awakens.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION_SET_REPETITIVE_ALARM)) {

                if(!isMyServiceRunning(context, PostReportsService.class)){
               
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        context.startForegroundService(background);
                    }else{
                        context.startService(background);
                    }
                }
            }
      }
```

Device above and below Oreo both reach context.startService(background) (or context.startForegroundService(background)), but only devices above Oreo actually start the service.
This only happens after the device is rebooted, otherwise the service works for both under and above Oreo. Is there anything specfic i could do to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the device I was testing on has power saving mode on that disabled the service on reboot.